# Finding the dimensions of a given group of vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

I was given the following question:

> Find the dimensions of all  vectors in $\mathbb{R}_3$ whose first and second entries are equal.

My logic is as follows: The vectors will fall into this category: $\left[\begin{matrix}a\\b\\x\\\end{matrix}\right]$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants and $x$ is in $\mathbb{R}$. $x$ must either be zero or a multiple of one - making the basis vectors $\left[\begin{matrix}a\\b\\0\\\end{matrix}\right]$ and $\left[\begin{matrix}a\\b\\1\\\end{matrix}\right]$. This means the dimension is two.

Is my logic sound? I know from the answer key that two is the correct answer, but am I arriving at this conclusion in a valid way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any vector in $\mathbb R^3$ with property " first and second entries are equal" is of the following form:
$$(a,a,b),$$
where $a, b$ are real numbers.

We see that
$$(a,a,b)=a (1,1,0)+b (0,0,1),$$
and $ (1,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ are independent.

Thus, we can conclude that dimension of  the mentioned space is 2.

Comment: I thought starting from $(a,b,c)$ if I have $(a,a,b)$ to have only two free incognites.

Answer (score 4):

No, you seem to have misunderstood the question. Any vector "whose first and second entries are equal" looks like $\begin{pmatrix} \xi \\ \xi \\ \eta\end{pmatrix}$ with $\xi,\eta\in \Bbb{R}$.

So, the answer is $2$, but your reasoning is incorrect.

Comment: So its not that the two vectors share the first two entries, its that for both of entry 1=entry 2 - and that entry may differ between the two of them.

Comment: @Burt right, the vector must have entry 1= entry 2 (they can be any number as long as they're equal) third entry can be chosen in any manner without reference to the first two. eg things like (1,1,2) or (1,1,0) or (2.5, 2.5, 9) are all elements of that subspace, but something like (1,0,1) or (2,1,9) is not.

Answer (score 3):

I do not understand your proof, but unless I am misreading your question, your set $\{(x,y,z):x=y\}$ is just the vertical plane at a $45$ degree angle wrt the positive $xy$-axis. It has dimension two because a basis for it as a subspace is $v_1=(1,1,0)$ and $v_2=(0,0,1).$

Comment: Very good both the users.